# How to set a typescript problemMatcher on npm task in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-problem-matcher

I compile some typescript files using webpack and this is defined as an npm script `pack-dev-tests` in my repo.

I used a task in VSCode for convenience, but I'd like to get the typescript errors from this npm script. I tried this, but the problem-matching does not work (I see the errors in the terminal but not in the problems):

```json
{
  "label": "Pack dev",
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "pack-dev-tests",
  "problemMatcher": {
    "base": "$tsc-watch",
    "applyTo": "allDocuments"
  },
  "group": "build",
}
```

Edit: I get the same thing with `"problemMatcher": [ "$tsc" ]`

Comment: what if you use `$tsc`, does it work if you specify the problem matcher full

Comment: @rioV8 I just tested and no, I get the same thing (errors in terminal but not matched in problems)